# The mathematics of Tug of War

Tags: reference-request, applications

Has anyone come across any paper on [Tug Of War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tug_of_war)?
I tried searching for it online but couldn't find anything. If anyone here has any sources, can you please share?

Regards

Comment: Parviainen, Mikko; Ruosteenoja, Eero Local regularity for time-dependent tug-of-war games with varying probabilities. J. Differential Equations 261 (2016), no. 2, 1357–1398. Ruosteenoja, Eero Local regularity results for value functions of tug-of-war with noise and running payoff. Adv. Calc. Var. 9 (2016), no. 1, 1–17. Manfredi, Juan J.; Rossi, Julio D.; Somersille, Stephanie J. An obstacle problem for tug-of-war games. Commun. Pure Appl. Anal. 14 (2015), no. 1, 217–228.  Del Pezzo, Leandro M.; Rossi, Julio D. Tug-of-war games ... Differential Integral Equations 27 (2014), no. 3-4, 269–288.

Comment: And a couple of older papers: Murzov, N. V. The solution of some dynamic tug-of-war and pursuit games. (Russian) Litovsk. Mat. Sb. 7 1967 119–127. Petrosjan, L. A.; Murzov, N. V. The n-person tug of war game. (Russian) Vestnik Leningrad. Univ. 22 1967 no. 13, 125–129.

Comment: But maybe you're really interested in the physics of tug of war, in which case I can recommend https://what-if.xkcd.com/127/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, on a lighter note, if you got all these from a simple google search...i should give up everything else and start working on my google skills. :-)

Comment: No, a search of MathSciNet, which is the online version of Mathematical Reviews (which is only available by subscription – but if you're at a university, your library may have a subscription, and your librarian will be happy to show you how to use it). Oh, the xkcd page I got from typing physics of tug of war into Google.

Comment: Alright then, I'll go right back to work.

Comment: Voting to reopen. It's essentially a reference request (I added that tag), so I'm not sure the "missing context" complaint is relevant.

Comment: @nimbus3000 You still should be find something using [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=mathematics+"tug+of+war"). (It would probably work a bit better some time ago, before Google Scholar abandoned search by subject area.)

Comment: Are you still there, nimbus?

Comment: yes sire, still here

Answer (score 0):

I was sort-of joking when I mentioned this xkcd what-if [essay](https://what-if.xkcd.com/127/) in the comments, but in fact there's a fair bit of mathematics there, as well as some links to the literature on tug of war.